# How to integrate firestore bundle builder - extension

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-extensions

I installed the firebase bundle extension in my project and started to configure

https://github.com/firebase/firestore-bundle-builder/tree/main/admin-dashboard

> ### Installation
>
> Clone this repository:
>
> ```bash
> git clone git@github.com:firebase/firestore-bundle-builder.git
> ```
>
> Install the dependencies:
>
> ```bash
> npm install
> ```
>
> Create a `.env` file in the root directory of the project and add the following environment variables:
>
> ```bash
> PROJECT_ID=your-project-id
> ```
>
> This project assumes that you have setup [Google Application Default Credentials](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) on your machine (a `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable pointing to a service account JSON file).
>
> Run the application:

?npm run dev
?```

I created an .env file and added a line

> PROJECT_ID=my-project-id

But not sure of json file, as I think it is already there, as I deploy function and hosting the application to firebase.

**Error:**

> Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
>
> admin-dashboard\node_modules@grpc\grpc-js\src\call.ts:81:17)

Please advice

Comment: It looks like you mostly just copied the readme from the repo here without modification.  That's not terribly helpful. Did you see the part where it says "This project assumes that you have setup Google Application Default Credentials on your machine (a GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable pointing to a service account JSON file)."?

Comment: I clearly mentioned what I did not do isn't and the reason - "But not sure of json file, as I think it is already there, as I deploy function and hosting the application to firebase.". I did no extra than read me steps, so pasted those 4 commands

Comment: "I think it is already there" isn't a very strong assertion.  We should be able to duplicate the problem based on the information you provide.  If you didn't provide a file with valid service account credentials, then it will certainly fail with a permission problem. This isn't a skippable step - you should edit the question to show what you did for this step so that we can do the same and observe the same result.  If you are actually very certain that you provided a file with service account credentials, then maybe you didn't provide the correct data.

Comment: works when used from gitbash ( does  not work from vscode terminal). I have functions like getProducts - functions.https.onCall(async (data, context). How can I create document paths - "A comma separated list of document paths. If specified, only these documents will be included in the bundle." for my above function ?